# Visualize 3 parameters in a graph

Tags: graphing-functions, visualization

How would one visualize 3 parameters, where 1 parameters depends on the other 2? I want to display the time on the y-axis which depends on the input value of two different types.

I can only think of a 3D graph or visualizing it with a plane graph, but I don't find this very descriptive.

Are there any alternatives?

The input values are as follows: (A,B):

(50,50)

(50,100)

(50,150)

(50,200)

(100,50)

(100,100)

(100,150)

(100,200)

(150,50)

(150,100)

(150,150)

(150,200)

(200,50)

(200,100)

(200,150)

(200,200)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can visualize assigning different color to different values of output, or using a gray scale..you can obtain something like this: [imagesc matlab](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fx_files/20516/3/imagescnan.png)